# Error(5,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" error while creating function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

```
Error(5,1): PLS-00103: 

Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:     

( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise return select update while with <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<    continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

Below the code I've written.

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION First_three_records
  RETURN NUMBER AS
  BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_emp ON COMMIT DROP AS
    SELECT *
    FROM   emp
    WHERE  deptno=20;

    INSERT INTO tgt
    SELECT *
    FROM   temp_emp;

  END;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37362/why-cant-we-write-ddl-statement-directly-into-the-pl-sql-block -- you need make use of Dynamic SQL if you're going to create temporary tables.

Comment: Don't create a temporary table in a function though. Oracle only has global temporary tables, not local ones like other RDBMSs.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not have local temporary tables, and you can't create objects within a PL/SQL block unless you use dynamic SQL; and it's very rarely necessary or a good idea. Your schema should be created in a controlled way, not on the fly.

You could use a collection instead but there is no point here, you can just do:

```
INSERT INTO tgt
SELECT *
FROM   emp
WHERE  deptno=20;
```

I'm not sure why you're wrapping that in a function at all; your function is also declared to return a number, but you have no `return` statement.